# how to have an image slider with one selector?

Tags: javascript, slider

There is an image slider with simply an `img tag` and four `<img>` tags as the selectors. I want to merge the selectors into one forward selector, but the `js` code does not work as I replace `i` with `i+1`.

Any help would be appreciated.

```js
function middle_pic(i) {
  document.getElementById('placeholder').src = 'images/products_center_middle_img' + i + '.png';
}
```

```html
<div id="middle-img-pic">
  <img src="images/products_center_middle_img1.png" id="placeholder">
</div>
<img src="images/selector.png" onClick="middle_pic('1');">
<img src="images/selector.png" onClick="middle_pic('2');">
<img src="images/selector.png" onClick="middle_pic('3');">
<img src="images/selector.png" onClick="middle_pic('4');">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `i` you passed to the function is not `int` and so `i+1` do not increment the value of `i`.

You can use `parseInt(i)` to parse integer out of string. And that should work

```js
var i=0
function middle_pic() {
  i=i+1;
  document.getElementById('placeholder').src = 'http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=Image' + (parseInt(i)+1);
}
```

```html
<div id="middle-img-pic">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=Image1" id="placeholder">
</div>
<img src="images/selector.png" onClick="middle_pic();">
```

Comment: You mean hide all and show only the next image to select ?

Comment: I mean instead of having four selectors, I have only one selector that every time I click on it, the next image appears.